# Can it possible to Subforms for a form in the Orbeon Form Builder?

Tags: orbeon, formbuilder

I've created a simple forms in Form Builder. But now I need a create a form which may need a kind of subform in it. Let me explain my scenario first. I have a form (Users) where I can fill all the user information. Now I want to add the activities/events list for the respective user. Here "events" is kind of form with 5 or 6 fields. Each user will have multiple events. How can I add events sub form for the users form?

Is it possible  to add a subform ("events") for the "users" forms? Or is it possible to add a separate section for "events" in the "user" form and able to add multiple events (Dynamic) for that respective user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a separate "events" form, I'd recommend you add an "events" section to your "user" form, and make that section a repeating section, so users of the form can add multiple events for a single user.

And if the number of fields you in "events" is small enough, you could even use a *repeated grid*, which will look like a table.